# Using ffmpeg to Compressed a Two Frame Video

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, video-encoding, video-editing

I'm trying to use [Ubuntu Linux 19.04](https://ubuntubudgie.org/blog/2019/03/27/19-04-release-notes) to convert an [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) video into a more efficient file-size.

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6PkaoxQULo) only contains two still images, and 20 minutes of audio, but for each file-type I save-as, the output-file is larger than 600MB.

Apparently I'm choosing the wrong lossless output file-type; you'd think a video like this would only be 10MB, since almost all the frames, in the entire video, are one of two frames.

Using ffmpeg, how can I convert this video to a format that understands how to compress all the duplicate frames efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is answered in the [ffmpeg examples](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow). You can use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i banner.png -i audio.wav -map 0 -map 1 -c:v libx264 -crf 16 -c:a aac -b:a 92k -shortest -movflags +faststart ready_to_upload.mp4
```

Detailed explanation:

- `-loop 1` repeat image potentially forever
- `-framerate 1` have a low frame-rate
- `-i banner.png -i audio.wav` input image and audio
- `-map 0 -map 1` use both stream
- `-c:v libx264 -crf 16` have high-quality image
- `-c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 92k` have high-quality
- `-shortest` stop repeating banner image when audio is finished
- `-movflags +faststart` include index at beginning of MP4 container for early start

It compresses to approximately 1 MB per minute.

Note: YouTube is likely (but not guaranteed) to re-encode your video. Image quality will degrade.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, there are actually two images in the video. The image changes near the end.

Comment: Same thing, do two videos, one for each image, and concatenate them...